# DataFrame convert datetime format

Tags: python, pandas

Would anyone advise me how to convert the datetime format?
the Python datetime format is shown. The data stored in the

```
                     DateTime       Open      Close   Volume        RSI Signle
0   2023-11-17 10:05:00+11:00  24.254999  24.250000    76690        NaN   HOLD
1   2023-11-17 10:10:00+11:00  24.240000  24.200001   102981        NaN   HOLD
2   2023-11-17 10:15:00+11:00  24.209999  24.200001   105351        NaN   HOLD
3   2023-11-17 10:20:00+11:00  24.190001  24.110001   125756        NaN   HOLD
4   2023-11-17 10:25:00+11:00  24.110001  24.120001    87926        NaN   HOLD
..                        ...        ...        ...      ...        ...    ...
67  2023-11-17 15:40:00+11:00  23.980000  23.969999    89735  48.844881   HOLD
68  2023-11-17 15:45:00+11:00  23.969999  23.990000   119233  55.458502   HOLD
```

My question how to i convert the datetime from to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS '2023-11-17 15:40:00' instead of 2023-11-17 15:40:00+11:00. I have tried the following but not working

```
dcsv = df.to_csv(header=None)
StringData = StringIO(dcsv)
df = pd.read_csv(StringData)
col_names = ['Datetime', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume', 'RSI', 'Signle']
df.columns = col_names
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], errors='coerce', utc=True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

PLease advise

Comment: There is no "conversion" here.  The column contains datetime values that happen to have a timezone.  You just don't like the way those datetime values get displayed by default.  You can use `strftime` to convert those to strings in your desired format, but after you do so, they will no longer be datetime values.

Comment: df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(arg=df["DateTime"]).dt.tz_localize(None)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're attempting to convert the 'DateTime' column from a string format to a datetime object and then reformat it to the desired string format. The approach you're using is close, but let's refine it a bit.

It appears that the 'DateTime' column in your DataFrame already contains datetime objects but is displayed with timezone information. To convert it to the desired format without the timezone information, you can use the `dt.strftime()` method after converting the column to a datetime type.

Here's an adjusted version of your code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Assuming 'df' is your DataFrame with the provided data
# This section of code reads the data you provided
data = '''DateTime,Open,Close,Volume,RSI,Signle
2023-11-17 10:05:00+11:00,24.254999,24.250000,76690,,HOLD
2023-11-17 10:10:00+11:00,24.240000,24.200001,102981,,HOLD
2023-11-17 10:15:00+11:00,24.209999,24.200001,105351,,HOLD
2023-11-17 10:20:00+11:00,24.190001,24.110001,125756,,HOLD
2023-11-17 10:25:00+11:00,24.110001,24.120001,87926,,HOLD
2023-11-17 15:40:00+11:00,23.980000,23.969999,89735,48.844881,HOLD
2023-11-17 15:45:00+11:00,23.969999,23.990000,119233,55.458502,HOLD'''

StringData = StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(StringData)

# Convert 'DateTime' column to datetime type and format it
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(df)
```

This code will read the provided data, convert the 'DateTime' column to a datetime type (without timezone information), and then format it into the desired string format. Adjust the data reading part (`data`) based on your original data source if needed.

Make sure the 'DateTime' column is recognized as a string column when reading the data, as converting to datetime is done afterward. Adjust the read_csv parameters if necessary to specify the column types explicitly.

Comment: AI-generated answers [are forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) on this website.